# How do you type hint functions with paths in python?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Lets said I want to make a super simple function which joins a basepath together with n-paths. How would I type hint this function.

**Here is an example:**

```
import os.path
from os import path
from typing import Union, Tuple, Optional

def joinPaths(basePath : str, *paths : Optional[str]) -> str:
    return os.path.join(basePath, *paths)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataPath = joinPaths('DataFolder', 'subfolder', 'subsubfolder', 'text.txt')
    print(dataPath)
```

**Output:**

```
"DataFolder\subfolder\subsubfolder\text.txt"
```

The ouput is correctly formatted for my needs.

I tried with the above code but 'mypy' gives

```
error: Argument 2 to "join" has incompatible type "*Tuple[Optional[str], ...]"; expected "Union[str, _PathLike[str]]"
```

I don't realy understand what this means and how to fix it

**Edit**
Fixed it with the following

```
import os.path
from os import path
from typing import Union, Tuple, Optional, TypeVar

PathLike = TypeVar("PathLike", str, None)

def joinPaths(basePath : str, *paths : Union[str, os.PathLike]) -> str:
    return os.path.join(basePath, *paths)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataPath = joinPaths('DataFolder', 'subfolder', 'subsubfolder', 'text.txt')
    print(dataPath)
```

Comment: Just hint as `def joinPaths(basePath: str, *paths: str) -> str:`, It's not optionnal, which means : value or None, here you have `str` and the `*` operator does the rest

Comment: I added the following line of code before the function:
`PathLike = TypeVar("PathLike", str, Path, None)`

and changed `*paths -> *paths : Union[str, os.PathLike]`

Which fixed it

Comment: str only is enough, if you pass only strings